# How to create a pokemon evolution kind animation in Android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-drawable, transitiondrawable

I want to create a basic "pokemon evolution" animation in my app , something like this:
[image]

I've been playing with this:

```
private void evolveAnimation(Pokemon selectedToEvolvePokemon) {
    Drawable backgrounds[] = new Drawable[2];
    Resources res = getResources();
    backgrounds[0] = res.getDrawable(selectedPokemon.getImage(getContext()));
    backgrounds[1] = res.getDrawable(selectedToEvolvePokemon.getImage(getContext()));

    TransitionDrawable crossfader = new TransitionDrawable(backgrounds);

    evolveTransition.setImageDrawable(crossfader);
    crossfader.setCrossFadeEnabled(true);

    crossfader.startTransition(3000); //The animation starts slow
    crossfader.reverseTransition(3000);
    crossfader.startTransition(2000);//It gets faster slow
    crossfader.reverseTransition(2000);
    crossfader.startTransition(1000); //And faster
    crossfader.reverseTransition(1000);


}
```

However , this is not working as expected in the GIF posted below , how can I fix this?

EDIT:

I've changed the method to this:

```
 private void doEvolve(TransitionDrawable crossfader, int durationMills) {
    crossfader.startTransition(durationMills);
    Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            crossfader.reverseTransition(durationMills);
        }
    }, durationMills);
    if (durationMills != 0) {
        doEvolve(crossfader, durationMills - 100);
    } else {
        crossfader.startTransition(0);
    }
}
```

However , works a bit strange.

Answer (score 1):

currently you are starting all transitions at once, they should be queued

for example you may use some `Handler` and its `postDelayed` method, e.g.

```
crossfader.startTransition(3000);

Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            crossfader.reverseTransition(3000);
        }
}, 3000); // will start after startTransition duration
```

pack this code into some method which will take `duration` param and some callback informing that start/reverse pattern ended, then call this method again with shorter duration

Comment: I've edited the question adding my adaptation of your snippet to my code , check it out to see whats missing please because it partially works.